# CANNOT COMPILE:: I don't understand my errors. Mostly the "declared as void" errors and "StudentType was not declared in this scope".

Tags: variables, compiler-errors, field

**I keep receiving these errors when I run the compiler:**

```
Program04.cpp:21:14: error: variable or field âgetDataâ declared void
Program04.cpp:21:14: error: âStudentTypeâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:21:26: error: expected primary-expression before â]â token
Program04.cpp:21:29: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
Program04.cpp:23:15: error: variable or field âsortDataâ declared void
Program04.cpp:23:15: error: âStudentTypeâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:23:27: error: expected primary-expression before â]â token
Program04.cpp:23:30: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
Program04.cpp:27:22: error: variable or field âcomputeAveragesâ declared void
Program04.cpp:27:22: error: âStudentTypeâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:27:34: error: expected primary-expression before â]â token
Program04.cpp:27:37: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
Program04.cpp:29:16: error: variable or field âprintDataâ declared void
Program04.cpp:29:16: error: âStudentTypeâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:29:28: error: expected primary-expression before â]â token
Program04.cpp:29:31: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
Program04.cpp: In function âint main()â:
Program04.cpp:34:1: error: âStudentTypeâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:34:13: error: expected â;â before âstudentsâ
Program04.cpp:37:9: error: âstudentsâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:37:19: error: ânâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:37:20: error: âgetDataâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:38:21: error: âsortDataâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:39:25: error: âcomputeAveragesâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:40:19: error: âprintDataâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp: At global scope:
Program04.cpp:45:14: error: variable or field âgetDataâ declared void
Program04.cpp:45:14: error: âStudentTypeâ was not declared in this scope
Program04.cpp:45:38: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
```

**Everything looks good to me, so i'm obviously not understanding something.
Any suggestions?**

---

PROGRAM FILE

---

```
using namespace std;
#include "StudentType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

const int MAX_STDS = 20;

void getData(StudentType[], int&);

void sortData(StudentType[], int&);

void getFormat(string&);

void computeAverages(StudentType[], int&);

void printData(StudentType[], int&);


int main () {

StudentType students[MAX_STDS];
StudentType();

getData(students, n);
sortData(students, n);
computeAverages(students);
printData(students);

return 0;
}

void getData(StudentType students[], int n){
    ifstream fin;
    int grade;
    string filename, name;
    bool done = false;

    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    while(true) {
       try {
         fin.open(filename.c_str());
         if(!fin) {
            throw(string("Could not open " + filename + "."));
         }
         break;
       }
       catch (string s) {
          cout << s << endl;
          cout << "Enter a different file name: ";
          cin >> filename;
       }
    }
    n=0;
    while(n<MAX_STDS && getline(fin, name)) {
       students[n].setName(getFormat(name));
       for(int i = 0; i < NUM_GRDS; ++i) {
          fin >> grade;
          student[n].setGrade(grade, i);
       }
       getline(fin, name);
       ++n;
    }
}

void printData(StudentType students[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       students[i].printLine();
    }
}

void computeAverages(StudentType students[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       students[i].computeAverage();
    }
}

void sortData(StudentType students[], int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
       for(int j=0; j < n-1-i; ++j) {
          if(students[j].getName() > students[j+1].getName()) {
             swap(students[j], students[j+1]);
          }
       }
    }
}

void getFormat(string& name) {
    string first;
    string middle;
    string last;
    char n, m;
    int size = 0;
    n = name.find(' ');
    first = name.substr(0, n);
    m = name.find(' ', n + 1);
    size = name.size();
    if (m != string::npos) {
       middle = name.substr(n+1, m-(n+1));
       last = name.substr(m+1, size - (m+1));
    }
    else {
       middle = "";
       last = name.substr(n + 1, size - (n + 1));
    }
    name = last + ", " + first;
    if (middle != "") {
       name = (name + ' ') + middle[0];
    }
}
```

---

HEADER FILE

---

```
#ifdef STUDENTTYPE__H
#define STUDENTTYPE__H

#include <string>
#include<iostream>

const int NUM_GRDS = 10;

class StudentType {
   public:
      StudentType();
      void setName(std::string);
      void setGrade(int, int);
      void computeAverage();
      std::string getName() const;
      void print(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;
   private:
      std::string name;
      int grades[NUM_GRDS];
      float avg;
};

#endif
```

---

IMPLEMENTATION FILE

---

```
#include "StudentType.h"
#include <iomanip>

StudentType::StudentType(){
    name = "";
    for(int i =0; i <NUM_GRDS; ++i){
       grades[i] = 0;
    }
    avg = 0.0;
}

void StudentType::setName(std::string newName){
    name = newName;
}

void StudentType::setGrade(int grade, int num){
    grades[num] = grade;
}

void StudentType::computeAverage(){
    float total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_GRDS; ++i){
       total += grades[i];
    }
    avg = total/NUM_GRDS;
}

std::string StudentType::getName() const{
    return name;
}

void StudentType::printLine(std::ostream& out) const {
    out.setf(std::left);
    out.setf(std::fixed);
    out.setf(std::showpoint);
    out << "\n" << setw(25) << "Student" << setw(50) << "Grades" << setw(10) << "Average" << endl;
    out << "_____________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
    out << std::left << std::setw(25) << name << std::right << ' ';
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_GRDS; ++i){
    out << std::setw(5) << grades[i] << ' ';
    }
    out << setprecision(2) << std::setw(6) << avg << endl;
}
```

---

**My output should look like this after the program compiles...**

---

```
Enter file name: grades.dat

Student                  Grades                                            Average
________________________________________________________________________________________
Last, First              90   80   70   60   50   40   30   20   10   0    45.00
Last, First              40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40   40.00
Last, First              54   98   65   32   21   87   54   65   98   32   60.60
Flames, Blood A          9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    4.50
Bottoms, Car             32   65   98   87   54   24   56   89   78   68   65.10
Guitars, Dean            10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10   10.00
Honer, Ruth T            78   56   12   23   45   89   31   64   97   79   57.40
Hot, Zepher R            12   54   87   89   56   32   51   46   97   31   55.50
.
.
.
```

**The input file should have this format and include over 20 students for testing purposes:
g0, g1,...g9 should be 10 grades ranging from 0 to 100**

```
First Middle Last
g0 g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9
First Last
g0 g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9
```

Comment: Changed line 1 of StudentType.h from #ifdef STUDENTTYPE__H to #ifndef STUDENTTYPE__H.

Comment: Declared int n; below the default constructor StudentType(); within the main function of Program04.cpp----
changed 'student[n].setGrade(grade, i);' to "students[n].setGrade(grade, i);' ----- (added the 's' to students)----
Deleted & from the parameter of void getFormat(string& name);

Comment: Changed Line 16 of the header file from void print(std::ostream& = std::cout) const; TO void printLine(std::ostream& = std::cout) const;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
#ifdef STUDENTTYPE__H
```

to

```
#ifndef STUDENTTYPE__H
```

then you have proper double-inclusion guard

(quite a common typo I must say)

Comment: This is the main error that was holding me back. All because of one character. I'm going to mark this question as answered on here to keep from cluttering this main error fix. If you wish to discuss this futher go here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/97640/             I will be finishing this program and updating the changes at the end of this week for those curious folk. Should be good practice so have at it. or visit the Reddit link: http://www.reddit.com/r/coding/comments/1bi2n3/please_take_a_look_at_this_c_code_im_having_a_bit/

Answer (score 0):

From taking a sharp look at your files, i spotted 2 main errors:

your include guard in the header file is messed up:

```
#ifdef STUDENTTYPE__H
#define STUDENTTYPE__H
```

you probably want:

```
#ifndef STUDENTTYPE__H
#define STUDENTTYPE__H
```

Also, in the program file:

```
void getData(StudentType[], int&);
```

does not match the implementation

```
void getData(StudentType students[], int n){
```

as it should be

```
void getData(StudentType students[], int& n){
```

which is also true for the other methods.

Also, i am not sure whether stackoverflow is the correct place for you, as you do not have a specific question but just seem to "debug" all your errors here. Maybe start with some c++ tutorials and try to use the error messages of the compiler to trace down all errors.

Comment: The prototype void getData(StudentType[], int&); is fine as it is just a prototype. Same goes for the actual function parameters. After fixing my guard, the ball is again rolling. I just overlooked this error MANY times and a few extra eyes aided me. For this, I thank all who gave feedback on the matter. If you wish to continue discussion on this question, feel free, otherwise I think I can complete this.

Comment: During compilation you will not an error as of the different signatures. But at link time you will! `f(StudentType[], int)` is different from `f(StudentType[], int&)`. Sooner or later you will need to fix this or your linker will complain about missing symbols as it can not find an implementation for `f(StudentType[], int)`. Please post your further compiler errors if you are not able to advance..